# Google Colab - Infinite recursion error using __getattribute__,__getattr__ and __setattr__?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, getattr, getattribute, setattr

Suppose I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self,val1,val2):
    print("In init")
    self.val1 = val1
    self.val2=val2
  def __setattr__(self,key,value):
    print("In setattr")
    #self.__dict__[key] = value # In order to access self.__dict__, __getattribute__ must be called
    super().__setattr__(key,value)

  def __getattr__(self,key):
    print("In getattr")
    y = str(input((f"No attribute found for {key}. Do you want to create one? ")))
    if y.lower() =='y':
      value = str(input("Enter value "))
      self.__setattr__(key,value)

  def __getattribute__(self,key):
    print("In getattribute")
    return super().__getattribute__(key)
```

`Employee(1,2)` returns a recursion error (**in **getattribute****), which is a bit surprising because I have used `super()` wherever I believed it's required. Could someone please explain precisely why this error occurs and how do I get over this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, always provide a whole traceback so we don't guess which line caused the error

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with the code you presented. Calling `Employee(1,2)` with this code prints `In init In setattr In setattr`.

Comment: `__getattr__` should not be interactive. If the attribute doesn't exist, let the user catch the `AttributeError` and define the attribute.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Strange that when I type the code in Google Colab, it returns a recursion error whereas when I run it VS code, it works perfectly fine

Comment: Python version(s)? VSCode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: In Colab, after the object is created, there's an additional attempt by the runtime to access your object's `__class__` attribute and a `_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist`. No recursion error (yet), but it does seem to constantly attempt to create various attributes that the runtime tries to access, independent of your actual code.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Python 3.7.15

Comment: @chepner Aah that probably explains why I am getting the recursion error. Thanks for that observation!

Comment: @chepner Holy cow, that is cancerous... Good to know. Won't touch that with a 10 foot pole.

Comment: In some sense, runtimes like this force you to have a good, *focused* reason for catching specific attributes.